# not getting associated product's sku in export CSV Magento 1.9.2

Tags: csv, export, associated-products, magento-1.9.2

I am trying to get associated product's Sku of configurable products in exported CSV file but not getting.

Here is my Action XML in "Dataflow-Advanced profiles" -

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[configurable]]></var>
    <var name="filter/sku"><![CDATA[]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/attribute_set"><![CDATA[20]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="store"><![CDATA[store]]></map>
        <map name="websites"><![CDATA[websites]]></map>
        <map name="attribute_set"><![CDATA[attribute_set]]></map>
        <map name="type"><![CDATA[type]]></map>
        <map name="status"><![CDATA[status]]></map>
        <map name="visibility"><![CDATA[visibility]]></map>
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[name]]></map>
        <map name="config_attributes"><![CDATA[config_attributes]]></map>
        <map name="associated"><![CDATA[associated]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>. 

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[product-Export.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

When I'm running profile, it's exporting a configurable product's CSV file but the last two columns (`config_attributes`, `associated`) are always coming out blank.

I checked `map()` of `app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Mapper/column.php` and print returning data of a product via `$row = $batchExport->getBatchData();`, but the printed array doesn't have the required fields.

Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong.